# Import data into EE database in a module - matrix error

Tags: matrix, pixelandtonic, module, plugin

I am importing data from another site via a module i am building. The channel I am importing to has a matrix field.

I am doing this like so:

```
    ee()->load->library('api');
    ee()->api->instantiate('channel_entries');
    ee()->api->instantiate('channel_fields');

    $data = array(
        'title' => 'TEST'
    );
    ee()->api_channel_fields->setup_entry_settings($this->customer_channel_id, $data);
    $success = ee()->api_channel_entries->save_entry($data, $this->customer_channel_id);

    $entry_id = ee()->api_channel_entries->entry_id;
```

Problem i am having is this error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Illegal string offset 'is_draft'
Filename: matrix/ft.matrix.php
Line Number: 2409

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Illegal string offset 'is_draft'
Filename: matrix/ft.matrix.php
Line Number: 2461
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you tell us your EE and Matrix version numbers?

Comment: EE 2.9.2 , Matrix 2.6.1

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible to get you to export the exp_matrix_data? There are a couple of scenarios that I can think could be causing this issue.

- Check and make sure that there is a a column for 'is_draft'. If you do not see one you need to manually or see the syntax below.

> ```
>       $this->EE->dbforge->add_column('matrix_data', array(
>           'is_draft' => array('type' => 'TINYINT', 'constraint' => '1', 'unsigned' => TRUE, 'default' => 0),          ));
> ```

- If that column is there can you provide both the export and sample file of the data being imported?

Comment: There is a field called is draft as its auto created by the matrix plugin.
I think its to do with how the matrix plugin hooks into the entry submission process, that there are hidden vars that get processed, but as i am creating entries via the api, the hidden vars don't exist hence it throwing an error.